# Vue2 - HTTP - Access to object value is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vuejs2

I'm learning VueJS 2.0 and I was trying to replicate what actually I'm doing using JS only in a similar situation: POST request to a server, get the response then store and manipulate the data Object.
I.E.

Parse the object and store in an array all the value for "base_TotalConsumptionKWH"

What is my issue here, is that I can't access the data because it return always undefined.

Below you'll find both the function I'm using to make the POST request and manipulate the data and the response I'm getting from the server.

Anyone has a clue of what I should do and can lead me to the solution?

Thanks a lot

Function

```
fetchData() {
        const headerRequest = {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "Postman-Token": "my-postman-token"
        };
        const dataRequest = {
            // Data for the request and auth token
        };
        this.$http
            .post(
                "https://example.com/my/endpoint",
                dataRequest,
                { headerRequest }
            )
            .then(
                response => {
                    return response.json();
                },
                error => {
                    console.log("something went wrong");
                }
            )
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                Object.keys(data.value).forEach(array => {
                    Object.keys(array).forEach(arrayItem => {
                        ComparisonCost.push(arrayItem.ComparisonCost);
                        // console.log(ComparisonCost);
                    });
                });
    });
     console.log(ComparisonCost);
    }
```

Response JSON

[image]

```
{ 
"0":{
"value": {
    "1": [
        {
            "base_SiteName": "base_SiteName",
            "base_SiteID": "base_SiteID",
            "base_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "base_MeterNumber": "base_MeterNumber",
            "month": 1,
            "year": 2018,
            "base_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-01-01",
            "base_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-01-31",
            "base_TotalConsumptionKWH": 90958.20000000001,
            "base_TotalCostExVAT": 8975.181360000006,
            "comp_SiteName": "comp_SiteName",
            "comp_SiteID": "comp_SiteID",
            "comp_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "comp_MeterNumber": "comp_MeterNumber",
            "comp_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-01-01",
            "comp_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-01-31",
            "comp_TotalConsumptionKWH": 47514,
            "comp_TotalCostExVAT": 4665.033783000008,
            "ComparisonKWH": 43444.20000000001,
            "ComparisonCost": 4310.147576999998,
            "ComparisonPercentKWH": 47.762818525432564,
            "ComparisonPercentCost": 48.022958022989684
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "base_SiteName": "base_SiteName",
            "base_SiteID": "base_SiteID",
            "base_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "base_MeterNumber": "base_MeterNumber",
            "month": 2,
            "year": 2018,
            "base_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-02-01",
            "base_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-02-28",
            "base_TotalConsumptionKWH": 98014.59999999999,
            "base_TotalCostExVAT": 9649.012121999993,
            "comp_SiteName": "comp_SiteName",
            "comp_SiteID": "comp_SiteID",
            "comp_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "comp_MeterNumber": "comp_MeterNumber",
            "comp_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-02-01",
            "comp_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-02-28",
            "comp_TotalConsumptionKWH": 51499.70000000001,
            "comp_TotalCostExVAT": 5079.6203340000075,
            "ComparisonKWH": 46514.89999999998,
            "ComparisonCost": 4569.391787999985,
            "ComparisonPercentKWH": 47.45711353206561,
            "ComparisonPercentCost": 47.35605811481629
        }
    ],
    "3": [
        {
            "base_SiteName": "base_SiteName",
            "base_SiteID": "base_SiteID",
            "base_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "base_MeterNumber": "base_MeterNumber",
            "month": 3,
            "year": 2018,
            "base_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-03-01",
            "base_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-03-31",
            "base_TotalConsumptionKWH": 95047.20000000001,
            "base_TotalCostExVAT": 9303.384390000003,
            "comp_SiteName": "comp_SiteName",
            "comp_SiteID": "comp_SiteID",
            "comp_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "comp_MeterNumber": "comp_MeterNumber",
            "comp_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-03-01",
            "comp_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-03-31",
            "comp_TotalConsumptionKWH": 49549.00000000001,
            "comp_TotalCostExVAT": 4908.856188000009,
            "ComparisonKWH": 45498.200000000004,
            "ComparisonCost": 4394.528201999994,
            "ComparisonPercentKWH": 47.86905874134114,
            "ComparisonPercentCost": 47.23580170162133
        }
    ],
    "4": [
        {
            "base_SiteName": "base_SiteName",
            "base_SiteID": "base_SiteID",
            "base_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "base_MeterNumber": "base_MeterNumber",
            "month": 4,
            "year": 2018,
            "base_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-04-01",
            "base_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-04-30",
            "base_TotalConsumptionKWH": 67865.40000000001,
            "base_TotalCostExVAT": 6793.280761999992,
            "comp_SiteName": "comp_SiteName",
            "comp_SiteID": "comp_SiteID",
            "comp_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "comp_MeterNumber": "comp_MeterNumber",
            "comp_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-04-01",
            "comp_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-04-30",
            "comp_TotalConsumptionKWH": 35570.50000000001,
            "comp_TotalCostExVAT": 3552.5614930000083,
            "ComparisonKWH": 32294.9,
            "ComparisonCost": 3240.719268999984,
            "ComparisonPercentKWH": 47.58669366127658,
            "ComparisonPercentCost": 47.70477450494615
        }
    ],
    "5": [
        {
            "base_SiteName": "base_SiteName",
            "base_SiteID": "base_SiteID",
            "base_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "base_MeterNumber": "base_MeterNumber",
            "month": 5,
            "year": 2018,
            "base_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-05-01",
            "base_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-05-31",
            "base_TotalConsumptionKWH": 60591.39999999999,
            "base_TotalCostExVAT": 6133.200416000003,
            "comp_SiteName": "comp_SiteName",
            "comp_SiteID": "comp_SiteID",
            "comp_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "comp_MeterNumber": "comp_MeterNumber",
            "comp_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-05-01",
            "comp_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-05-31",
            "comp_TotalConsumptionKWH": 36971.1,
            "comp_TotalCostExVAT": 3689.9367740000075,
            "ComparisonKWH": 23620.29999999999,
            "ComparisonCost": 2443.263641999996,
            "ComparisonPercentKWH": 38.982924969550126,
            "ComparisonPercentCost": 39.83668356289361
        }
    ],
    "6": [
        {
            "base_SiteName": "base_SiteName",
            "base_SiteID": "base_SiteID",
            "base_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "base_MeterNumber": "base_MeterNumber",
            "month": 6,
            "year": 2018,
            "base_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-06-01",
            "base_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-06-30",
            "base_TotalConsumptionKWH": 59018.4,
            "base_TotalCostExVAT": 6012.63405999999,
            "comp_SiteName": "comp_SiteName",
            "comp_SiteID": "comp_SiteID",
            "comp_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "comp_MeterNumber": "comp_MeterNumber",
            "comp_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-06-01",
            "comp_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-06-30",
            "comp_TotalConsumptionKWH": 38126.1,
            "comp_TotalCostExVAT": 3806.6399840000104,
            "ComparisonKWH": 20892.300000000003,
            "ComparisonCost": 2205.99407599998,
            "ComparisonPercentKWH": 35.39963807897198,
            "ComparisonPercentCost": 36.68931210491768
        }
    ],
    "7": [
        {
            "base_SiteName": "base_SiteName",
            "base_SiteID": "base_SiteID",
            "base_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "base_MeterNumber": "base_MeterNumber",
            "month": 7,
            "year": 2018,
            "base_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-07-01",
            "base_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-07-31",
            "base_TotalConsumptionKWH": 69856,
            "base_TotalCostExVAT": 7044.543480000005,
            "comp_SiteName": "comp_SiteName",
            "comp_SiteID": "comp_SiteID",
            "comp_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "comp_MeterNumber": "comp_MeterNumber",
            "comp_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-07-01",
            "comp_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-07-31",
            "comp_TotalConsumptionKWH": 45620.8,
            "comp_TotalCostExVAT": 4534.806129000008,
            "ComparisonKWH": 24235.199999999997,
            "ComparisonCost": 2509.737350999997,
            "ComparisonPercentKWH": 34.69308291342189,
            "ComparisonPercentCost": 35.62668550666672
        }
    ],
    "8": [
        {
            "base_SiteName": "base_SiteName",
            "base_SiteID": "base_SiteID",
            "base_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "base_MeterNumber": "base_MeterNumber",
            "month": 8,
            "year": 2018,
            "base_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-08-01",
            "base_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-08-31",
            "base_TotalConsumptionKWH": 64291.4,
            "base_TotalCostExVAT": 6499.826138000006,
            "comp_SiteName": "comp_SiteName",
            "comp_SiteID": "comp_SiteID",
            "comp_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "comp_MeterNumber": "comp_MeterNumber",
            "comp_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-08-01",
            "comp_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-08-31",
            "comp_TotalConsumptionKWH": 42775.399999999994,
            "comp_TotalCostExVAT": 4276.4563150000085,
            "ComparisonKWH": 21516.000000000007,
            "ComparisonCost": 2223.3698229999973,
            "ComparisonPercentKWH": 33.466373418528775,
            "ComparisonPercentCost": 34.20660454287363
        }
    ],
    "9": [
        {
            "base_SiteName": "base_SiteName",
            "base_SiteID": "base_SiteID",
            "base_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "base_MeterNumber": "base_MeterNumber",
            "month": 9,
            "year": 2018,
            "base_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-09-01",
            "base_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-09-30",
            "base_TotalConsumptionKWH": 59688.4,
            "base_TotalCostExVAT": 6044.662429999991,
            "comp_SiteName": "comp_SiteName",
            "comp_SiteID": "comp_SiteID",
            "comp_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "comp_MeterNumber": "comp_MeterNumber",
            "comp_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-09-01",
            "comp_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-09-30",
            "comp_TotalConsumptionKWH": 34832.899999999994,
            "comp_TotalCostExVAT": 3479.3308350000098,
            "ComparisonKWH": 24855.500000000007,
            "ComparisonCost": 2565.3315949999815,
            "ComparisonPercentKWH": 41.64209461134828,
            "ComparisonPercentCost": 42.439617178092526
        }
    ],
    "10": [
        {
            "base_SiteName": "base_SiteName",
            "base_SiteID": "base_SiteID",
            "base_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "base_MeterNumber": "base_MeterNumber",
            "month": 10,
            "year": 2018,
            "base_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-10-01",
            "base_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-10-31",
            "base_TotalConsumptionKWH": 71110.8,
            "base_TotalCostExVAT": 8822.500767999994,
            "comp_SiteName": "comp_SiteName",
            "comp_SiteID": "comp_SiteID",
            "comp_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "comp_MeterNumber": "comp_MeterNumber",
            "comp_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-10-01",
            "comp_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-10-31",
            "comp_TotalConsumptionKWH": 37339.999999999985,
            "comp_TotalCostExVAT": 4317.601640999985,
            "ComparisonKWH": 33770.80000000002,
            "ComparisonCost": 4504.89912700001,
            "ComparisonPercentKWH": 47.49039527047933,
            "ComparisonPercentCost": 51.06147616716209
        }
    ],
    "11": [
        {
            "base_SiteName": "base_SiteName",
            "base_SiteID": "base_SiteID",
            "base_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "base_MeterNumber": "base_MeterNumber",
            "month": 11,
            "year": 2018,
            "base_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-11-05",
            "base_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-11-30",
            "base_TotalConsumptionKWH": 71893.00000000001,
            "base_TotalCostExVAT": 8909.277705666656,
            "comp_SiteName": "comp_SiteName",
            "comp_SiteID": "comp_SiteID",
            "comp_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "comp_MeterNumber": "comp_MeterNumber",
            "comp_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-11-05",
            "comp_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-11-30",
            "comp_TotalConsumptionKWH": 34601.6,
            "comp_TotalCostExVAT": 4016.6514930000003,
            "ComparisonKWH": 37291.400000000016,
            "ComparisonCost": 4892.626212666656,
            "ComparisonPercentKWH": 51.870696729862445,
            "ComparisonPercentCost": 54.91608157589195
        }
    ],
    "12": [
        {
            "base_SiteName": "base_SiteName",
            "base_SiteID": "base_SiteID",
            "base_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "base_MeterNumber": "base_MeterNumber",
            "month": 12,
            "year": 2018,
            "base_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-12-01",
            "base_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-12-31",
            "base_TotalConsumptionKWH": 85631.79999999999,
            "base_TotalCostExVAT": 10497.040625464515,
            "comp_SiteName": "comp_SiteName",
            "comp_SiteID": "comp_SiteID",
            "comp_GasOrElectric": 1,
            "comp_MeterNumber": "comp_MeterNumber",
            "comp_StartDateWholeMonth": "2018-12-01",
            "comp_EndDateWholeMonth": "2018-12-31",
            "comp_TotalConsumptionKWH": 41705.50000000001,
            "comp_TotalCostExVAT": 4788.554291712896,
            "ComparisonKWH": 43926.29999999998,
            "ComparisonCost": 5708.486333751619,
            "ComparisonPercentKWH": 51.296714538290665,
            "ComparisonPercentCost": 54.38186377885918
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: your console.log(ComparisonCost); is outside of promise function.

Comment: Object.keys() gives you an array of keys, not values. So you have to reference the value, something like data[0].value[key][index].base_SiteName . Or use Object.values() or Object.entries() . But I'm having a hard time figuring out the format of the data. [{"value":{"1":[{"props":"vals"}]}}] ?

Comment: @Shilly you're right about the use of object.keys. I'll try the iteration using object.entries.

When it comes to the data format, the structure is:

    [{
      "value":{
                   "1":[
                       {"props":"value"}
                     ]}}]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `Object.keys(data.value)` to `Object.keys(data[0].value)`

You miss "0" property of data object

Comment: thanks for trying but that isn't the issue. I'm getting closer with the suggestion from Shilly.

Answer (score 0):

Following the tip from @Shilly, I finally managed to get those data. 
I've used the Object.values to read all the values in it (array) and then the iteration to push out all the data.
Thanks!

```
.then( data => {
             Object.values(data["value"]).forEach(array => {
                    array.forEach(arrayItem => {
                        // do whatever you whant
                    });
                });
            });
```